# Can't connect to oracle DB using SQLPLUS on Ubuntu with (Easy Connect)

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, sqlplus

I am trying to connect to a corporate db using this connect format

`sqlplus user/pass@url:1521/dbname`

And I'm getting

`ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`

This is the same connect string I use to connect to the DB with Toad and query the database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yessir, I just put the format in to hide my company's info. Will edit now.

Comment: Try `user/pwd@//url:1521/servicename`

Comment: Gave it a shot @EgorSkriptunoff and same error.

Comment: Well, it looks like sqlplus wants a listener up.  You should have an $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora file configured.  Login as oracle, and use lsnrctl to start the listener. http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Lsnrctl

Comment: I think the listener is up since I can connect to it fine on TOAD.

Comment: Did you pick up from @EgorSkriptunoff's comment that you have to supply the service name, not the SID, when using this format? It isn't clear what `dbname` represents. Toad might be using the SID and a different connection method if everything else is the same. Check what *services* are reported by `lsnrctl services`.

Answer (score 0):

The Easy Connect format only accepts a service name, not a SID. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm#i498306):

> This naming method provides out-of-the-box TCP/IP connectivity to
>   databases. It extends the functionality of the host naming method by
>   enabling clients to connect to a database server with an optional port
>   and service name in addition to the host name of the database:
>
> ```
> CONNECT username@[//]host[:port][/[service_name][:server]][/instance_name]]
> Enter password: password
> ```
>
> The connect identifier converts to the following connect descriptor:
>
> ```
> (DESCRIPTION= 
>   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host)(PORT=port))
>   (CONNECT_DATA=
>     (SERVICE_NAME=service_name)
>     (SERVER=server)
>     (INSTANCE_NAME=instance_name)))
> ```

If `dbname` in your original attempt represents the SID, then you'll need to find out the service name instead. You can get that from `lsnrctl services` on the server, or `select value from v$parameter where name = 'service_names'` (if you have permission), or from SQL*Plus you can `show parameter service_names`, though that doesn't really help you if you can't connect to SQL*Plus... If Toad is using a TNS alias then it might also be in your `tnsnames.ora` already.